# Change Primary Key field to unique field

Tags: django, django-models, django-shell

When setting up my database structure, I was stupid enough to set a field called "student_id" as "primary_key=True" for my Student class. I only realised much later that there are (rare) occasions where it is necessary to change said "student_id". When doing that via a form, Django will automatically duplicate the student, which is not what I want.

I would like to change "primary_key=True" to "unique=True", and am wondering how to do that.

My current plan is to add a field called "id" to the Student class, apply the migrations, and to go into the shell and simply assign it a running number with a for loop:

```
counter = 0
for s in Student.objects.all():
    counter += 1
    s.id = counter
    s.save()
```

I would then go back into my models.py and change the line "primary_key=True" to "unique=True". How do I make sure that Django then treats the "id" field as it would with classes without a primary key (ie automatically assign a new ID when a new student is added to the database)?

Comment: The model is quite simple: it has a field called "student_id" with "primary_key=True" and lots of other, not really relevant fields - last_name, first_name, studying_since and so on.

Comment: i think you would require renaming->migrating->renaming->migarting cycle to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a foolproof guide, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

When you add the `id` field, use an `AutoField` instead of an `IntegerField`. The `AutoField` takes care of incrementing when you add new objects.

Once the field has been created and populated, you can set `primary_key=True`, and remove it from your `student_id`.

Eventually, you should be able to remove the explicit `id` field from your model, since Django automatically creates one if you don't set a primary key manually.

Comment: And will I need to set the new IDs manually in the running version (as I suggested in the question)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would expect so.