# How to migrate from custom primary key to default id

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a model with email address as custom primary key as follows:

```
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, primary_key=True,)
```

Now I realized that this is not a good idea in my case and I would like to go back to the automatically generated id field as primary key.

How to do this? I tried this in different ways but all failed. I am using Django 1.10.4 with Python 3.4.3 with an SQLite database.

1. I just replaced the primary_key=True option by unique=True. `python manage.py makemigrations` complains:

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to user without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

If I specify `0` as default value, `python manage.py migrate` fails with `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: login_user.id`

2. Based on this post [Change Primary Key field to unique field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275531/change-primary-key-field-to-unique-field#32275673) I tried to add an Autofield manually, as in:

   id = models.AutoField()

Now `python manage.py makemigrations` fails with:

```
login.User.id: (fields.E100) AutoFields must set primary_key=True.
```

If I do as suggested by the error message,  I get the same issue as in my first try: missing default value.

3. I tried to make a field id=IntegerField(unique=True) (following Django documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields) and then change the field type to AutoField(primary_key=True).  At the same time,  I need to change the email field to unique=True to avoid having two primary keys.  After these changes,  `makemigrations` works fine but `migrate` fails with a traceback and this error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: duplicate column name: id`   It seems to be trying to make an additional 'id' column, don't know why.

What is the correct way to do this?  Also,  if it succeeds,  will ForeignKey fields that refer to my User be updated correctly?

Comment: You want to introduce a new column, that should be a primary key and therefor unique - setting the default to `0` only works, if there is just one record present (in all installation) - your migration file needs to populate real `id`s for all present records. The documentation should cover this topic.

Comment: Yes I understand that user 0 for all id's will not work,  but I cannot find in the documentation how to populate the id's for present records.  I have checked https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/ ;  is there anywhere else I should look?

Comment: To populate the id field, I first need to create it.  This is what makemigrations/migrate is supposed to do (as I understand it) but that fails, as explained above. I cannot populat the id field before it is created,  so I am stuck.

Comment: @dahrens Sorry I just realized that I should have added your name in my previous comments - still new to stackoverflow.

Comment: This might be worth reading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields

Comment: @dahrens The method explained in your link works for unique fields but not for primary_key fields,  because it requires you to temporarily create the new field with a null value.  AutoFields do not accept null values, not even temporarily.

Comment: and if you start with a plain field with `unique=True` to populate your values and change the field later to become your `primary_key`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130802/discussion-between-ygramoel-and-dahrens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This situation is hard to tackle particularly on sqlite which actuall doesn't even have a [real ALTER TABLE statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

> SQLite supports a limited subset of ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE
> command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or to add a new
> column to an existing table.

Most of the type, django is doing the changes via a temp table. So you can do that too

**Step 1:** Create a new model, exactly like

```
class TempModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    # other fields from your existing model
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly declare a primary key field. Merely switching it off in the email field is sufficient.

**Step 2:** make migrations and migrate

**Step 3:** open your favourite database client and do a:

```
INSERT INTO myapp_tempmodel(fields,....) SELECT * FROM myapp_oldmodel
```

**Step 4:** delete old table, make migrations and migrate

**Step 5:** rename temp table, make migrations and migrate

Comment: I will try it now.  I see one potential issue: I have some other tables that refer to User with a foreignkey field. I will have to find a way to move these to the new table.
Would it be possible to automate step 3 (and include it in the migration framework) using a RunPython migration?

Comment: if it's just one table, drop and recreate the FK and you are done, if it's multiple you would need a runpython in your migrations since it's too much work to do it one by one.

Comment: This worked but was absolutely not easy, especially because I tried to avoid manual intervention so that migrations would continue to work. Doing manual interventions in the database is probably not a good idea in that case.

Comment: Step 4 was tricky. I tried to test my code at this point, which requires changing the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting, and I did not systematically use django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()
or backend.settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.  Also,  renaming the active user model (and simultanuously changing AUTH_USER_MODEL) fails during migration, with KeyError: 'id' (don't know why). I had to copy the NewUser table back to a new User table.

Comment: Some of the makemigrations seem to create migration files in django.contrib.admin which is part of my env and not in git.  The point is that logentry refer to the current user model, which further compilcates stuff ... I don't believe that these changes can be re-run to migrate another database ...

Comment: no probably not but that can be overcome by squashing the migrations. That way all the changes are merged into one

Answer (score 7):

I have come across this problem myself and ended up writing a reusable (MySQL-specific, though) migration. You can find the code in this [repo](https://github.com/salvalcantara/django-change-pk). I've also written about it in my [blog](http://salvalcantara.com/blog/the-motherfucker-migration/).

As a summary, the steps taken are:

1. Modify your model class like this:

   ```
   class Something(models.Model):
       email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   ```
2. Add a new migration along these lines:

   ```
   app_name = 'app'
   model_name = 'something'
   related_model_name = 'something_else'
   model_table = '%s_%s' % (app_name, model_name)
   pivot_table = '%s_%s_%ss' % (app_name, related_model_name, model_name)
   fk_name, index_name = None, None 


   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       operations = [
           migrations.AddField(
               model_name=model_name,
               name='id',
               field=models.IntegerField(null=True),
               preserve_default=True,
           ),
           migrations.RunPython(do_most_of_the_surgery),
           migrations.AlterField(
               model_name=model_name,
               name='id',
               field=models.AutoField(
                   verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True,
                   primary_key=True),
               preserve_default=True,
           ),
           migrations.AlterField(
               model_name=model_name,
               name='email',
               field=models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True),
               preserve_default=True,
           ),
           migrations.RunPython(do_the_final_lifting),
       ]
   ```

   where

   ```
   def do_most_of_the_surgery(apps, schema_editor):
       models = {}
       Model = apps.get_model(app_name, model_name)

       # Generate values for the new id column
       for i, o in enumerate(Model.objects.all()):
           o.id = i + 1
           o.save()
           models[o.email] = o.id

       # Work on the pivot table before going on
       drop_constraints_and_indices_in_pivot_table()

       # Drop current pk index and create the new one
       cursor.execute(
           "ALTER TABLE %s DROP PRIMARY KEY" % model_table
       )
       cursor.execute(
           "ALTER TABLE %s ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)" % model_table
       )

       # Rename the fk column in the pivot table
       cursor.execute(
           "ALTER TABLE %s "
           "CHANGE %s_id %s_id_old %s NOT NULL" %
           (pivot_table, model_name, model_name, 'VARCHAR(255)'))
       # ... and create a new one for the new id
       cursor.execute(
           "ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s_id INT(11)" %
           (pivot_table, model_name))

       # Fill in the new column in the pivot table
       cursor.execute("SELECT id, %s_id_old FROM %s" % (model_name, pivot_table))
       for row in cursor:
           id, key = row[0], row[1]
           model_id = models[key]

           inner_cursor = connection.cursor()
           inner_cursor.execute(
               "UPDATE %s SET %s_id=%d WHERE id=%d" %
               (pivot_table, model_name, model_id, id))

       # Drop the old (renamed) column in pivot table, no longer needed
       cursor.execute(
           "ALTER TABLE %s DROP COLUMN %s_id_old" %
           (pivot_table, model_name))

   def do_the_final_lifting(apps, schema_editor):
       # Create a new unique index for the old pk column
       index_prefix = '%s_id' % model_table
       new_index_prefix = '%s_email' % model_table
       new_index_name = index_name.replace(index_prefix, new_index_prefix)

       cursor.execute(
           "ALTER TABLE %s ADD UNIQUE KEY %s (%s)" %
           (model_table, new_index_name, 'email'))

       # Finally, work on the pivot table
       recreate_constraints_and_indices_in_pivot_table()
   ```

   3. Apply the new migration